# How can I shorthand my code to "print(//some text)?"

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript, and I am working on this code, but part of it requires me to continuously send new alerts to the screen. I found a way to print the messages straight on the screen, and it works perfectly.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to shorten it further. It's not a super big issue, other than it looks cleaner to me, but mostly its just once i get an idea in my head i want to figure how to do it. For example, as you can see in the code below, right now I use:

```
const show = document.getElementById('htReadOut');

show.innerHTML = `some text`;
```

BUT I'd like to reduce the second line further to just be

```
print = `some text`;
```

I tried making a function and an object type, but get an error that the the id's in the new html aren't defined.

I tried making a constant variable so that print would be short for show.innerHTML, but I get an error when I try to use "print = someText" since it thinks I'm trying to redefine print.

Comment: If you just want to remove the `show` variable then you can simply do: `document.getElementById('htReadOut').innerHTML = 'some text';`  Aside from that, any other changes you want to make would depend on what you're trying to do with those changes.  From the description it sounds like you're essentially trying to create your own syntax for performing these operations, which won't work.  You *can* put code in functions, you *can* alias functions/properties/etc. into a variable, etc.  Regarding any specific attempt, we'd need to see that attempt to help with it.

Comment: @David, no, I'm trying to shorten it. I suppose in a sense yes, I was trying to create a new syntax though. So I guess maybe it's not possible. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The answer below sounds like what you want then.  Note that in your question title you (almost) use the correct syntax for calling a function: `print("some text")`  But then in the question you try to *assign* to the function instead: `print = "some text"`  Calling a function and assigning to a variable are two very different things.

Comment: @David oh, my bad sorry about that. I'm more or less self-teaching myself. I've done the intro to JS course on sololearn, but other than that I just got an open source code for the snake game and then started tinkering with it to figure out what everything does and how to change it and add new things. I added a setting to turn walls on and off, and moved the game over pop-up to display on screen so far :)

Comment: Two downvites on this question may seem like a bit much.  Neither of them are mine, for what it's worth.  And, honestly, it's best not to take them personally.  I guess I'm not *super* familiar with the banning rules as it's never come up.  But in general the advice would be to make sure you always focus on the specific technical problem, including the specific code you've written (not just a description of it) and the specific error you're getting (not just a description of it).  [This](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) is a good reference on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your code like this. Then, you can use the print function as much as you want to print the message to the screen. If you are only using *show* with text, you don't need to use innerHTML, it is enough to just use innerText like in the example below.

```
const show = document.getElementById('htReadOut');

function print(message) {
    show.innerText = message;
}

print("Hello");
```

Comment: The OP could even move the `show` variable entirely into the function, if nothing else needs it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but what I'm entering is supposed to be html code and this just turned it all into text :/

Comment: On second thought, I just switched innerText to innerHTML and it worked perfect! Thank you!

Comment: glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try this...

```
const show = document.getElementById('htReadOut');

function print(element, sometext) {
    element.innerHTML = sometext;
}

print(show, 'Hello, world!');
```

every time when you have an element you want to write text in it, just pass that element and the text into the print function